# How to make only part of a button react on user actions (click/hower/etc) based on graphical shape in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

The question is a bit difficult to explain, but I will try.

I have an image of a button:

[image: The base button image]

And I also have some animations of it, such as (gif with a single loop, reload it to view the animation!):

[image: Animated button]

Also, I have some kind of a pattern:

[image: The button pattern]

So, now the question: how to make the button react (for example on clicks/hower/etc) only when the mouse is INSIDE the black part of the pattern, and disallow such reactions when the mouse is out of the scope of this pattern? Without modifiyng the graphical files of course. And of course the pattern itself should be invisible.

I want to make that with help of C++ and Qt.

Just please indicate me at least the path, which functions/classes of Qt should I look for! Because now I am completely lost.

Comment: I forget the details, but in Qt you can have a mask that selects which portion of an image is "live" to touch.  You have to get into the image layer stuff, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way I can think of doing this, is installing an event filter on the particular button, by calling the `void QObject::installEventFilter ( QObject * filterObj )` method of the button. Documentation can be found [here](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#installEventFilter).

What it boils down to, is creating a QObject specifically for the purpose of filtering mouse events, based on a binary image. All you have to do is override the `bool QObject::eventFilter ( QObject * watched, QEvent * event )` method of this new object, and then install that object as the filter for the button. As part of the constructor for this filter class, pass it a reference to the binary image. This binary image reference will sit as a member variable in the filter object, and we can use it to decide which pixels of the button respond to mouse events.

In the `eventFilter` method:

- Check the event type, if it is not a mouse event, don't handle the event yourself, pass it on to the parent class
- If it is a [mouse event](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qmouseevent.html), then you're in business.
- Get the x and y position of the mouse event using the corresponding methods `x()` and `y()`
- Look into the binary image stored as a member variable. If the binary image  is `true` at that point, do one thing, otherwise do something else

This filter class should be generic enough that you can create multiple instances of it with different binary images for different buttons/widgets.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you please explain what is the best way to check the mouse event coordinates against the pattern? And will be the pattern itself invisible? I can't get that.

Comment: I edited my answer to clarify that a bit better. Hopefully it makes more sense.

Comment: Can't understand how an image can be "true" or "false". It seems that you are talking about some call to some function, but I don't get which one. Also - do I need to position this QObject exactly at the same place as the button itself? And I should pass in the constructor of this filter QObject the pattern image, am I right?

Comment: I guess I'm simplifying things a bit, but the point is, your mask image has two colors- one that denotes an area where the button responds, and the other color denotes the "background" area. Denote these two colors as "true" and "false" respectively. You are essentially checking whether the pixel in the binary image at the mouse event position is of a particular color/value, and deciding what to do.

Comment: It seems I finally understand. Just getting the mouse cursor position and assuming it as the X and Y of the pattern image, and just checking the color at the given coordinate, something like that?

Does the eventFilter receive the x() and y() position relative to the original button or to the filtering QObject?

Comment: Yep, you've got the gist of it. Unfortunately, the devil is in the details, and the X, Y positions might not exactly fit the image dimensions- this can be due to the fact that the button widget has padding, thus offsetting these potitions. You can either force the button to not have any sort of padding/margin etc. or calculate these offsets in your event filter and act accordingly. The X and Y positions should be relative to the widget that is receiving the mouse event- ie the button.

Comment: Thank you! In any way I am going to unset all paddings, so that should not pose any problem for me. Will mark now as the solution, will write here again if I got any questions after the test. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple way to do this:

http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#setMask

> Masked widgets receive mouse events only on their visible portions.

This will also mask the drawing, however, so you may want to try an alternate route:

1. Subclassing QPushButton,
2. rewrite the mousePressEvent to clip against a mask,
3. rewrite the paintEvent.

I list rewriting the paint event last because you may be able to get the desired effect without it. However, if you wish to have animation, it may be necessary.

I would also suggest using a polygon mask (via QPolygon) rather than a bit mask and containsPoint(...) to determine if a mouse event occurs inside the masked area. In my experience it's a bit less painful, and easy to debug: You can add the code to draw the polygon over the graphic, removing that code when you're satisfied it's no longer needed.